# Query for mail and php mail function

Tags: php, email

Is it correct? Because it don't send emails notification to my email account.

```html
  //mail
  $aquery = "SELECT u.email FROM users u, email_notifications e WHERE u.id = e.users_id AND e.leaves ='yes'";
  $adminget = mysqli_query($link, $aquery) or die(mysqli_error($link));

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($adminget)) {
    $emails[] = $row['email'];
  }

  $admin = "myemail@abc.com";
  $applicant = $email;
  $subject = "Tomato Portal: New Leave Submission";

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From:" . "Tomato Portal<info@abc.com>". "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Cc: $applicant" . "\r\n";
  

  mail($admin,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: maybe you should show us some code so we can talk about what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

When a user have registered then after completing the registration a mail will forward to the site Admin that must be you (As per your asking question).
You have to use mail() function to send the email functionality.

```
 mail("admin@example.com","My subject","Email Body");
```

As you want to get all the form details into your email then within email body you have to set all the desired details. Like Bellow:

```
 $subject= "Demande de devis Transports Schwartz ";

 $body= '<table border="0">
                    <tr>Vous avez '. $recu .'une demande de devis via le site internet.</tr>
                    <tr><td>Date: <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $create_at .'</span></td></tr>
                    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Nom: <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $name .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>'.$soci.' : <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $societe .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>E-mail: <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $uemail .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>'.$tell.': <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $phone .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>  
                        <td>Date '.$denl.' : <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $de .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr>  
                        <td>Date de livraison : <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $dl .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Lieu '.$denl.' : <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $enlevement .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Lieu de livraison : <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $retour .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Nature des marchandises : <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $marchand_nature .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Type de '.$veh.' : <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $vehicle .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Dimensions: <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $dimensions .'</span></td>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Poids: <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $poids .'</span></td>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>  
                        <td>Aide au chargement avec grue : <span style="color:#4472c4;" >'. $chargement .'</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>D&eacute;tails de la demande : </td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="color:red;">'. $votre_demande .'</td></tr>
                </table>';

  $mailsent= mail( "admin@example.com", $subject, $body );
```

And for that you have to set ('text/html') as Content type is in email header.

Comment: How can you be sure this is the solution when it is impossible to know what's wrong with their code?

Comment: Yes absolutely, but on that time asking user code was not present here.

Answer (score -1):

For sending the mail you have to use mail() function as below :
 **mail("admin@example.com","My subject","Email Body");**